# Laravel unit tests output write to a log file

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I need to write my unit tests output, simply assertion results to a logfile. I have created a custom log file and through Laravel `Log::channel` I can write a some dummy content to the log file while executing the unit tests.

But I couldn't find any approach to write the assertions output to a log file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can use the [log fake package](https://github.com/timacdonald/log-fake).